Launch another app using deeplink flutter
I currently try to integrate payment feature in my app. Most of the payment will open a their own webview page. When want to complete the payment, some of the case that I found is that users will need to open their (payment) app either manually or by click provided button.
My current issue is that when user click the button, my app unable to launch it. The value inside the button is a deeplink to the app.
I have try some of the package such as external_app_launcher. Yes, It can open the app but only initiate it. Since this is the payment process, the app should directly open payment page or verification page as it should. I also try to use url_launcher package but seems not working.
i'm using webview_flutter package to open webview in my app.
Is there any ways to launch another app from my flutter app using deeplink?

You should probably use a package like url_launcher to launch the url for the payment page. It would then most likely automatically deeplink to their payment app if that app has that feature. In any case that's the payment app's responsibility, not yours
